# How do I add to a child observableArray in knockoutjs?

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel, ko.observablearray

I am relatively new to knockoutJS and I have mutiple viewModels.

Here is a JS Fiddle that creates campaigns, I want to have a secondary table that list the line items for the campaign that was just added.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmann/rd4pa3xo/

I want to create a campaign that contains multiple lineItems.
I want the IO in the lineItem to be the foreign key to the campaign.
So I want the field listed in the html to display campaign Name from the newCampaign but I also want to add LineItem fields (ProductType)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the model I am playing with:

```
var ViewModels = function () {
var self = this;
self.newLineItem = {
    ID: ko.observable(),
    IO: ko.observable(),
    CampaignID: ko.observable(),
    ProductType: ko.observable()
}
self.newCampaign = {
    ID: ko.observable(),
    IO: ko.observable(),
    Name: ko.observable(),
    LineItems: ko.observableArray()
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div data-bind="with:newLineItem">
<div class="form-group" data-bind="with:newCampaign">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCampaignLineItem" data-bind="value:Name" placeholder="Campaign" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProducType" data-bind="value:ProductType" placeholder="ProductType" />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Line Item</button>
```

Comment: You are on the right track. If you could be a little more specific as to what exactly you are not being able to do, that would be good. Right now, your question is too open-ended.

Comment: I just updated the jsFiddle with a better view now.  You can create campaigns, but I did not wire up the lineItems, because it was causing some binding errors, which is my problem.

Comment: Then go ahead and cause the binding errors so we can see whats going on! :) What you probably need is a way to mark one Campaign as "selected" and then display that Campaign's data and lineItems. Your "newLineItem" looks good, and so does your function.

Comment: Just updated my jsFiddle again.  I got it adding the lineItems correctly now.  And it is adding it to the newCampaign array, which is bound to the other grid successfully.  YAY!  Now, I just need to pull in a value from the parent object (campaign) that identifies the IO/ID  THANK YOU!  Isolating the problem always solves it right?  Thanks again.